# What is the difference between libicucore.dylib and libicucore.A.dylib?

Tags: ios, dylib

I'm sure the .A means something, but searching for it yields nothing but noise.  Please enlighten me.

[image]

Comment: I need to pick one to link to, and I'm not sure of the implications.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh, they're the same.

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  4969408 Sep 25 16:06 libicucore.A.dylib* 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       18 Oct  7  2011 libicucore.dylib@ -> libicucore.A.dylib
```